# Why is "module.exports = (req, res) => {" stopping my routing from working

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes

A href is called like so:

```
<a class="navlink" href="/auth/logout">Logout</a>
```

When clicked a controller in the middleware(named "auth.js"), and another controller "logout.js" is called , it doesn't do anything. The session should destroy and redirect the index. Instead the pay flinches slightly but stays on the current page.

"auth.js"

```
const User = require('../database/models/User')

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    User.findById(req.session.userId, (error, user) => {
        if (error || !user) {
            return res.redirect('create')
        }

        next()
    })
}
```

logout.js"

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy(() => {
        res.redirect('/')
    })
}
```

I expect the controller to direct to the index.

Comment: how are you importing, mounting?

Comment: i'm new to javaScript so i'm not quite sure what you mean by importing. Would this be in my main controller? index.js? where i import the controller with the code above?

Comment: paste your other code where you've something like `require('./filename)`

Comment: Ah okay, I understand you. A href is called like so: <a class="navlink" href="/auth/logout">Logout</a>. This called the a controller in the middleware:  const User = require('../database/models/User')
 
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    User.findById(req.session.userId, (error, user) => {
        if (error || !user) {
            return res.redirect('create')
        }
 
        next()
    })
}

Comment: you should probably post all relevant code in question, the one you pasted above doesn't look like it's got anything to do with the code in your question

Answer (score 0):

If the button is ultimately triggering an ajax call through the controller to your server, then ajax calls don't by themselves pay any attention to redirect responses (so thus the `res.redirect()` does nothing).  You would have to have code in the client-side controller that sees that redirect response from the ajax call and then acts on it by setting `window.location` accordingly to cause the browser page to change.

Things in the browser that do automatically follow a redirect in the response:

- Type a URL in the URL bar of the browser
- Following a link in a web page (such as `<a href="xxx">Click here</a>`)
- Setting `window.location` via Javascript
- The response from a form post (submitted automatically by the browser, not via Javascript)

So, if your request is being sent via Javascript, then it won't automatically follow a redirect response.  Your Javascript would have to see the response come back, see that it's a 3xx response, fetch the redirect location from the response and then set `window.location` to tell the browser to go to that new location.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Does this still apply if a href is called like so:              <a class="navlink" href="/auth/logout">Logout</a>

Comment: @TobasiA - No.  A link will follow the redirect.  The only two things that follow a redirect are a top level browser request (typed in the URL bar or following a link or setting `window.location`) or a form post (not done with Javascript).  See edits to my answer.

Comment: @TobasiA - We can't judge your code based on a tutorial.  We'd have to see the relevant portion of your actual code to advise further.